# What is seismic stretch in geophysical method?

Tags: geophysics, seismic

What is seismic stretch in geophysical method ?

Comment: this https://wiki.seg.org/wiki/NMO_stretching ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because although I'm glad you want to participate, you've got to have enough in your question to show you've done a little research.

Comment: @Spencer, then the reason for closing is that it is unclear what they are asking. The question is definitely on topic

Comment: @aretxabaleta Other sites such as History SE have an "off-topic" close reason for this situation.

Comment: See also [this SE Meta question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102811/should-a-clear-lack-of-research-be-grounds-for-closing-a-question) in regards to more input on the issues with such a question.  It's not even necessarily the lack of research entirely always... it's that such questions are so bare-bones and broad (and often just people trying to get help on homework).

Comment: Deepak an easy way for you to fix the issues some have and make it more helpful and insightful to a greater variety of people would be to mention where you've come across seismic stretch and what specifically you are interested in knowing/understanding about it?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are referring to - as @ye-ti-800 has already pointed out - the apparent stretch that results from the NMO correction applied to CMP gathers. There is a great tutorial supplied by a Leading Edge article that may be accessed here: https://wiki.seg.org/wiki/Step-by-step_NMO_correction. It is important to note, though, that the article does not go into details about stretch **mute**. The article just goes into the specific details of the "mechanics" occurring during a conventional NMO correction and accompanied stretch that results from it.

Comment: If by chance you, Deepak, struggle with some of the technical terms in this answer (as honestly I'd figure many novices would... and indeed I'm not familiar with many of them myself either)... this would show how it's good to ask a more precise question about what you want to know and perhaps what audience level would be helpful. Because it would probably seem reasonable for a scientist knowledgeable in the topic that if you're advanced enough to have encounted such a technical term, you may well know most of the terminology connected to it! So try to refine your question if this doesn't help.

Comment: And looks like a solid answer Nate, much appreciated!